# The default value of \newcommand is not as documented

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

The documentation of `\newcommand` in `latex2e.pdf` claims that if the optional parameter is specified as `[]` and is not given in the call, the value will be the string `def`. Instead, the command is getting the null string. Is this a documentation error or a bug?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

%Font for sequence
\newcommand \seqname [1] {\bm{\mathit{#1}}}

% Set former {x|P(x)} and {x,y,z}
% Trusting documentation
\newcommand {\setof} [2] []
   { \ifthenelse {\equal{#1}{def}}
       {\{ #2 \}}
       {\{ #2 | #1 \} p1=#1}
   }

%Explicit default
\newcommand {\setxx} [2] [noP]
   { \ifthenelse {\equal{#1}{noP}}
       {\{ #2 \}}
       {\{ #2 | #1 \} p1=#1}
   }

\begin{document}
Test setof x,y,z = $\setof{x,y,z}$

Test setof x P(x) = $\setof[P(x)] {x}$

Test setxx x,y,z = $\setxx{x,y,z}$

Test setxx x P(x) = $\setxx[P(x)] {x}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: You must have misread it.  An unspecified optional argument that is defined as `[]` indeed produces the null argument.  One typical way to test for it is `\ifx\relax#1\relax...\else...\fi`.  This will only fail if by chance an optional argument was specified that began with the token `\relax`.

Comment: Exactly where does `latex2e.pdf` say this?

Comment: To second @daleif's question: Are you referring to p. 59 of [LaTeX2e: An *unofficial* reference manual](http://home.gna.org/latexrefman/)? (emphasis mine)

Comment: some random pdf that you found (on the internet (you don't say what the document is?) isn't the same as the documentation of the system.

Comment: That seems to be a different version of the latex2.pdf that I was reading, and the wording has changed. BTW, the page number for 12. Definitions in the PDf version is 61. I've downloaded it and will replace the old version.

Comment: @shmuel but no documentation that is provided by the latex maintainers is in a file called latex2e.pdf so whatever the file is (some tutorial of some sort, presumably) it is not the system documentation

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just ran texdoc on latex2e on my tl15 box. So it seems to be in tl

Comment: @daleif _lots_ of things are in TL:-), and texdoc will pick up the first thing with latex2e in its name, but still the phrasing of the question implies that it's the documentation of the system rather than a 3rd party tutorial, and that is far from the case. (Actually it's from Karl/et al so probably fairly reliable but still...)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle exactly why I wanted to know exactly what was being referred to. But at least in my version there is no mention of def as the default

Comment: @werner, it's on the latex site so it's not exactly "some random pdf that you found ";  IAC, the 2015 and 2016 versions are different from the two versions that I had, and I've switched to the August 2016 version.

Answer (score 7):

I've never seen mention of `def` being the default value when an argument is not specified. It's rather the *second optional* argument to `\newcommand` that gets substituted when the optional argument to the defined macro is absent.

So if you do

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2][def]{#1-#2}
```

the call `\foo{x}` will result in

> def-x

whereas the call `\foo[y]{x}` will result in

> y-x

You can easily check that

```
\newcommand {\setof} [2] []
   { \ifthenelse {\equal{#1}{def}}
       {\{ #2 \}}
       {\{ #2 | #1 \} p1=#1}
   }
```

will print

> {x|}p1 =

if called `$\setof{x}$`. Only `\setof[def]{x}` would print

> {x}

which of course is not what you want.

A correct definition would be

```
\newcommand{\setof}[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \{#2\}% no optional argument (or empty)
  \else
    \{#2\mid#1\}p1=#1%
  \fi
}
```

It's even easier with `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\setof}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\{#2\}}% no optional argument
    {\{#2\mid#1\}p1=#1}%
}
```

where `o` denotes an optional argument (with no default value) and `m` a mandatory argument. The presence or absence of the optional argument is checked with `\IfNoValueTF`.

Comment: I've been playing with xparse, and it gives me "! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]." when I call \tl_gset_eq:NN. It also treats _ as a regular character even when I use expandafter. Also, I don't understand how to emit \\. Not that any of those relate to my original question, but I'd like to start using it if I can get comfortable with it.

Comment: @shmuel I'm not sure what the problem are, but surely they aren't connected with the code here.